# How do I create a variable which goes up with '1' everytime it's used and resets at the end of the month?

Tags: php, date, variables, userid

I'm still quite new to php and javascript etc, and I'm doing my register.php file for an app I'm working on and now I want every user who registers to get an unique ID and this is what I got:

```
<?php echo date("Ymd") ?>
```

This gives me (right now) 20161005 and I want this to be part of my ID's for my users and then I want to add a number to that for example

```
$userID= date('Ymd') + some number
```

This number should begin from 1 again in the beginning of the next month so my database doesnt get to many number in the end :)

This combination of those 2 numbers will be my User ID's which will help me to deter whoms data to load in the app and so on.. ^^

Is that possible to realise with php?

Comment: This is not possible by means of a "variable", since a variable is not persistent over requests. You have to use some form of a persistent storage for that. Typically one uses a database for such stuff.

Comment: I would suggest not using the ID to store additional data, best practice the ID in any table should be either a unique natural key ( a part of the data ) or a unique surrogate key ( not a part of the data ).  Its better to use an auto increment ID ( which you can set as a property in the DB ) and then store this other data in a separate field it will be easier to query later.  You'll also be better storing the creation time as either a DateTime, or Timestamp type.

Comment: For reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html and http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not to say you are doing it wrong, but you should consider using the AUTO_INCREMENT property built into the DB.  This will give you a integer number that automatically increases with each insert.

You can set it as an Attribute of the table,

dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

And then when doing inserts you just leave that field out, and magically it will be incremented.  If you need to use it immediately after doing the insert you can get its value with ( in MySqli )

```
  mysqli_insert_id( $db );
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Then for the created time, you should use a proper data type such as a timestamp or datetime.  This too can be set to have a default value of `NOW()` the current time.  Then when you do date based queries you can use things like `MONTH( create_date )` to find all users that singed up in a given month etc..

Here is a wiki page on what I meant by Surrogate key

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surrogate_key

Basically it's just a unique identifier not derived from the actual data.  Then being these are users a good example of a Natural key would be the email address, being that users email should be unique in most cases.